# Prolog - custom operator to check list

Tags: list, prolog

I am working on a few tutorials and am currently stuck on this:

The `isSingleton` operator is a unary prefix operator that checks that its list operand has exactly one element.

For example:

```
?- isSingleton [].
false.
?- isSingleton [-8].
true.
```

How do I make an operator that checks if the list contains one variable?

Comment: Can you describe in Prolog what a list of one element looks like?

Comment: I managed to get it, the answer was:
:- op(500, fy, isSingleton).
 isSingleton [_X|[]].

Comment: That's about right. You can simplify it a bit since `[_X | []]` is the same as `[_X]` since `| []` means it has an empty tail. Or you can even just use `[_]` in this case, so `isSingleton [_].`. The term `[_]` is an anonymous one-element list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Basic syntax

```
functor([1,2,3],F,A).
```

Issuing the above query unifies `F` with `'.'` and `A` with 2.
So, a list is a typical [cons-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) represented by a binary term `.(Head,Tail)`, where `Head` is an element and `Tail` a sublist. We could also destructure a list with the [`=../2`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/EDD-2.html) predicate:

```
[1,2,3] =.. X.
```

The above unfiies `X` with `[., 1, [2, 3]]`. If we apply the same approach on a singleton list, here is what we have:

```
[1] =.. X.

X = [., 1, []]
Yes.
```

The empty list is denoted `[]`, which is an atom named `"[]"`.
Knowing all the above, we can produce lists using only basic Prolog dot term:

```
.(A,.(B,[])) = [A,B].

Yes
```

#### Syntactic sugar

As hinted above, the bracket notation is syntactic sugar for `./2`, and …

```
[H1, …, Hn | T ]
```

… stands for

```
.(H1,( … .(Hn, T) … ))
```

In particular, "`| T`" can be omitted when `T` is the empty list `[]`. That is why it is possible to write, for example, `[a,b,c]` to represent the `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))` list.

#### Singleton

A singleton list containing the element `V` is then represented by `[V]`, which stands for `.(V,[])`. In your comment, what you did right is the operator declaration:

```
:- op(500, fy, isSingleton).
```

You added a useless "`|[]`" cons with the empty-tail, but the reason `isSingleton [_X|[]]` fails here is because there is no such predicate defined. You can of course write it in a file and load it, but since you only need one simple clause, you may also use `compile_term/1`:

```
compile_term(isSingleton([_])).
```

By definition, `isSingleton` succeeds if and only if its first argument can be unified with a list whose tail is empty. We don't care about its head, which explains the anonymous `_` variable (your original `_X` adds little information, but is correct too). Finally, the following works:

```
isSingleton [3].

Yes.
```

Comment: Which system says `A = A
B = B`??

Comment: @false ECLiPSe (http://eclipseclp.org). If your concern is that the output is useless, I agree. SWI-Prolog does not print it and I think it is not necessary to keep that in the answer.

Comment: Displaying `A` and `B` has some point: It insists that the set of solutions comprises all terms for `A` and `B`. That's in a way more accurate that saying `true`. On the other hand, the `true` (from e.g. SWI) has to be seen w.r.t. to the variables of the actual query. In any case, the toplevel is not standardized, and given the development in recent years (that is, display of determinism, constraints) we can be quite happy that it has not been standardized 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks coredump for your detailed answer, managed to get it sorted. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @AndrewCreevey - if this answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer to give credit to the respondent.

Comment: @NicholasCarey sorry im new to this, I think I have now accepted it correctly.